# Big number in JavaScript gets altered

Tags: javascript

I have a API that returns JSON object with field that was of type long on the server side. I noticed that the number gets malformed on client side. This is a sample:

```
var tmp = JSON.parse("9410110000000363");
console.log(tmp); // output: 9410110000000364

var tmp2 = 9410110000000363;
console.log(tmp2); // output: 9410110000000364
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: JavaScript numbers are only accurate up to around `4503599627370496`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point - JS numbers (at least until we get value types in ES.next.next) are IEEE 754 floats.

Comment: Interestingly, `9410110000000363+1` is also `9410110000000364`, and `9410110000000363-2` is `9410110000000362`. :)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes, of course it is, this is what the IEEE 754 specification means. I'm sure there is a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Here [**read this**](http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html) this is an excellent source.

Comment: You can try work with big numbers with this http://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum